# Laptop won't boot (dual boot XPS 15 9500)

Tags: boot, laptop, multi-boot

I have a dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 - Windows 10 Dell XPS 15 9500 laptop. It was functioning perfectly for a long time. Yesterday I used Windows for the first time in a long time. It did some updates of Windows and of Dell support assist. Today (the first boot after the Windows boot) the laptop won't boot. If I turn it on the dell logo appears the keyboard lights up. Then both dim. Then the laptop retries the same repeatedly. If I press F12 I can go to the one time boot settings. When I select either ubuntu or Windows Boot Manager in the column UEFI Boot Devices it attempts to boot and gives a beep.

---

On an another attempt it said explicitly
"No bootable devices found."

---

A diagnostic quick test (selected from F12 menu) finds no problem.

When I run support assist i get a black screen with a blue pixel in the upper left corner.

---

[Repairing grub](https://askubuntu.com/a/182863/800252) I encounter the error

```
GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition (>1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag). This can be performed via tools such as Gparted. Then try again.
Alternatively, you can retry after activating the [Separate /boot/efi partition:] option.
```

Selecting the partition labeled EFI System as EFI partition in the advanced settings I instead get the question:

```
LegacyWindows detected. You may want to retry after deactivating the [Separate /boot/efi partition:] option.
Are you sure you want to continue anyway?
```

I am not sure what to do about this. Can I try this safely?

---

I think the issue is not any hardware failure. I've managed to find at least my personal files on Ubuntu and they seem to be intact.

---

Comment: I tried starting ubuntu from an USB stick in order to repair grub as suggested. I fail at the step to mount my original partition. It says "Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command."

Comment: Windows has overwritten your bootloader. That is quite common. You could try the [manual method](https://askubuntu.com/a/831241/1178017) . It helps to get familiar with the procedure as windows does this quite often.

Answer (score -1):

I've had kinda similar problems. What helped me was inserting ubuntu bootable device and restoring grub. I hope it will help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).